# Why is async programming needed in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, threadpool

I have a problem with the concept of `async` in NodeJS. I have read a lot about the event poll in NodeJS. They say things like:

> The event loop is what allows Node.js to perform non-blocking I/O
>   operations

or

> Node uses the Worker Pool to handle "expensive" tasks. This includes
>   I/O for which an operating system does not provide a non-blocking
>   version, as well as particularly CPU-intensive tasks.

or

> These are the Node module APIs that make use of this Worker Pool such
>   as File System(fs)

So, I found that Node manages I/O running using a Thread pool. Now my question is, if Node is managing them, why do we need to utilize `async programming` at all in NodeJS? And whats the reason behind some modules like **BlueBird**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tl;dr:** You need `async` to prevent a blocking of the Event-Loop.

---

NodeJS uses a certain number of threads to handle clients. There basically are two types of threads:

- Event Loop (or your main thread)
- Worker Pool (or threadpool)

---

### The Event Loop:

Basically the reason why async programming is needed:

Once all events are registered, NodeJS enters the Event Loop and handles all incoming requests as well as outgoing responses. All of them pass through the Event Loop.

### Worker Pool

As you already said, NodeJS uses the Worker Pool to perform I/O and CPU intensive tasks .

### Asynchronous Code

In order to prevent blocking the main thread, you want to keep your Event Loop clean, and delegate certain task. This is where async code is needed. That way your code becomes non-blocking. The terminology concerning async and non-blocking is a bit vague though. To clarify:

- **Async Code:** Performs certain tasks in parallel
- **Non-Blocking:** Basically Polling without blocking further code.

In NodeJS however, Async is often used for I/O operations. There it doesn't just mean "perform in parallel", because it mostly means "don't block and get the signal".

So in order to make the Event Loop of NodeJS efficient, we don't want to wait for an operation to finish. Therefore we register an async "listener" instead. This allows NodeJS to efficiently manage its own resources.

---

**BlueBird** (or Promises in general):

Libraries like [BlueBird](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird) which you mentioned, aren't required anymore because NodeJS supports promises out of the box (see note [here](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird#note)).

Promises are just another way of writing asynchronous code. So are [Async/Await](https://javascript.info/async-await) and [Generator Functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*).

Side note: Functions defined with the `async` keyword actually yield a promise.

Comment: The point of Promises is to manage and coordinate co-routines, and the usage of async keyword does more than yielding a promise, it permits suspending and resuming execution inside of a function without blocking.